# Actualizar un campo de la misma tabla con Subquery que crea ranking

Tags: mysql

Objetivo: Crear un ranking dia por día, cual es el almacén  que vende más, será el número 1, y así sucesivamente.

Los campos de la tabla son:

```
Date, Store, Sales, Rank_Sales_By_Date
```

Me gustaría saber si es posible con una sola consulta, o con qué método, puedo actualizar la columna Rank_Sales_By_Date, con esta información, en el momento que tengo Una consulta parcial, filtrada con una fecha ('2017-02-19'), pero el objeto es que lo hace, clasificado por fecha, para todas las fechas.

Luego la consulta que tengo, :

```
UPDATE 
    scraper_data_twitter AS T1,
(
    SELECT
      Ntweets AS Ntweets_var,
    (
      SELECT 
        COUNT(Ntweets) + 1
      FROM 
        scraper_data_twitter 
      WHERE 
        (NTweets > Ntweets_var) AND fecha = '2017-02-19'
    ) AS rank
   FROM 
      scraper_data_twitter 
   WHERE 
      fecha = '2017-02-19'
   GROUP BY SITE, fecha
   ORDER BY NTweets_var DESC
) AS A
SET T1.rnk_Ntweets =  rank
```

Me guarda siempre el valor 1.

asi:

[image: Resultado consulta SIN UPDATE]

[image: Resultado CON UPDATE]

Se que es probable mejorar la consulta, por lo que sus sugerencias en cuanto a la mejora de la consulta son Bienvenidas.

Comment: Nos puedes mostrar qué estructura tienen tu tabla `scraper_data_twitter`? Y por favor, acláranos qué quieres hacer. Por lo que entendí, quieres actualizar el valor de rnk_Ntweets de toda la tabla acorde a los tweets que registraste cada día, pero en tu imagen no aparece el campo fecha.

Answer (score 1):

Hola Encontre la solucion la comparto:

```
set @Lastfecha = NULL, @Lastntweets = NULL, @CurRange = NULL;
update scraper_data_twitter t
set rnk_ntweets= if(@Lastfecha<=>t.fecha, 
                               if(t.NTweets<=>@Lastntweets, 
                                     @CurRange, 
                                     @CurRange:=@CurRange+1),
                               @CurRange:=1 + cast((@Lastfecha:=t.fecha) as DATE) - T.fecha + (@Lastntweets:=T.NTweets) - T.NTweets);
```